# ASP.NET WebForms vs. ASP.NET MVC for Shared Web Hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, webforms, shared-hosting

I am looking into creating a web application that will live on a shared web hosting provider. The majority of my professional work involves internal Asp.Net web form development on dedicated servers. I have not developed with MVC before, so my knowledge about its strengths and weaknesses is lacking.

The application will allow users to create personal accounts and develop fan fiction stories. I will probably be incorporating OAuth for handling authorization. I also want leave room for growth, in the event that payments are ever taken on the site.

Which framework would give the best performance on this type of production environment?

Comment: If it is a new web application, MVC could be a best choice. In the old days, lack of wrappers could be a con of choosing MVC. Now, I don't see any con of using MVC except the learning curve. ***FYI:** You cannot ask opinion based question in SO.*

Comment: I rephrased the question to better address my needs. I'm not too worried about learning curve (worked with ASP and PHP in the past) so I feel like that will help with understanding MVC.

Comment: I had an ASP.NET webforms application and to rewrite in MVC, I decided to do a somooth transition. I replaced controls that caused postbacks such as <asp:Button> with html controls and javascript. I changed <asp:gridviews> for <asp:repeater>, and kept those <asp:formviews>  that sent data to the server. And I realized that was good enough for me, I didn't complete the transition. ASP webforms can be good enough if you avoid server controls that do undesirable postbacks. You must have some html javascript knowledge, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go for Asp.net MVC and never look back to Web form again
The point is it doesn't necessarily mean that you cannot develop the same kind of application in web form that you can in Asp.net MVC but the ease and flexibility and of course testable from the ground up that Asp.net MVC has to offer is not comparable to Web form development.
Start on some professional Asp.net MVC book and get your hands dirty developing some small application and moving all the way up to professional and more sophisticated application that deals with OAuth and various aspect of the application you are trying to develop.

Asp.net MVC is getting better.....